# Firebase dynamic link doesn't work after install from App store

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have following case:

1. Click Firebase Dynamic URL, for a deleted application. App store is opened
2. Install this application from App Store.

The expected result here is to handle action for this link, e.g go to given View Controller, but nothing happens.

Is this supported on iOS because this case works on Android?

Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    if let activityDictionary = launchOptions?[.userActivityDictionary] as? [String : AnyObject],
        let userActivity = activityDictionary["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as? NSUserActivity {
        return handleDynamicLink(userActivity: userActivity)
    }

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    return handleDynamicLink(userActivity: userActivity)
}


private func handleDynamicLink(userActivity: NSUserActivity) -> Bool{
    // Handling here ... 
    return true
}
```

Here is diagnostics report that looks ok:

```
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ----
Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 2.3.2
System information: OS iOS, OS version 11.2.1, model iPhone
Current date 2018-07-05 07:16:14 +0000
Device locale en-GB (raw en_GB), timezone Europe/Sofia
    Specified custom URL scheme is com.app and Info.plist contains such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.
    AppID Prefix: 123, Team ID: 123, AppId Prefix equal to Team ID: YES
performDiagnostic completed successfully! No errors found.
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end ----
```

Comment: Are you checking the box in the interstitial screen that copies the link to the pasteboard? To survive installation, the link has to be written there.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, I don't get what you mean?

Comment: When you click the deep link, there should be a page before you are redirected to the app store - that is where the deep link is stored from.

Comment: Hi, Ian, I have facing the same error can you explore more